# SQL with condition problem to get the data

Tags: mysql

I am using SQL 5.5. I have a problem to select the data in the SQL with condition.

My condition is:
For example, my jabatan_yang_akses is 7,table name is `abc`

1. First need to check the jabatan_yang_akses is 7 in the category_id is 4
2. Second check the parentid if jabatan_yang_akses is 7 in the category_id is 4
3. Then check the parentid is equal to id, find the id in category_id is 3,
4. Then continue to find the parentid is equal to id, find the id in category_id is 2,
5. Then check the parentid is equal to id, find the id in category_id is 1,
6. The last will show the name in the table only category_id are 1 and 2

```html
 id |        name                      | jabatan_yang_akses | category_id | parentid
1          100 John                           12                  1              0
2          100-1 David                        10                  2              1
3          100-1-1 Shawn                  12，7                   3              2
4          100-1-1-1 Peter                12，7                   4              3              
5          100-1-1-2 Zack                     7                   4              3        
6          100-1-1-3 Wing                     6                   4              3   
7          100-1-1-4 Peter                    7                   4              3
8          100-2 Heng                         9                   2              1
9          100-1-2 Laurence                   7                   3              2
11         100-3 Jason                        7                   2              1
12         200 Zip                            8                   1              0
13         200-1 Lol                          9                   2              12
14         200-1-1 Joke                       10                  3              13
15         200-1-1-1 Kila                     7                   4              14
```

So, I want the expected result like below the table:

```html
 id |        name                      | jabatan_yang_akses | category_id | parentid
1          100 John                           12                  1              0
2          100-1 David                        10                  2              1
11         100-3 Jason                        7                   2              1
12         200 Zip                            8                   1              0
13         200-1 Lol                          9                   2              12
```

I try to use below SQL query to select, but doesn't work. Hope someone can guide me to solve this problem. Thanks.

```
select id,name,jabatan_yang_akses,category_id,parentid 
from abc 
where ((concat(",",7,",") like "%,'7',%")  OR (jabatan_yang_akses='7')) AND category_id IN（1,2）
```

Comment: Thanks Akina help me to modify. Can you help me on this SQL problem?

Comment: `concat(",",7,",") like "%,'7',%"` What a strange expression? PS. Do not use dquotes for strings, use them in JSON paths only.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me to modify my SQL query ?

Comment: No, I can understand neither the logic nor the algorithm. Try to add to each your step the phrase like "so the rows id=?,?,? are checked because their ids were checked on the step ? and their column ? is ?" - this will help to understand what you try to achieve.